# User Interface. Multiple select with priority

Tags: user-interface, usability

I'm designing user interface and want to ask your advises how to make it more user-friendly. Please tell any suggestions and if you have ever seen implementation of something familiar please share the link.

University. There are 40+ specialities grouped into 5 faculties. User choose several he is interested in and than orders them by priority.

For example I am interested in "programming microcontrollers", "system analysis" and "experimental physic". I must find them quickly in "programming faculty", select them and then order - what I prefer most and what I prefer less then others I select.

Any ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes and radio buttons would be appropriate for this, for both websites and desktop applications.

In my case I'd use the faculty names as headers and then add the according specialities below them, prefixed by checkboxes and radio button next to each speciality, allowing the user to set the priority.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
http://i45.tinypic.com/2ex6jy0.png

Comment: Yes, but how would you prioritize selections? Checkbox have two states but several states are required. If I uses checkboxes I tell: "I am interested in A as well as in B as well as in C". But somehow I should tell: "I am interesetd in A, then in B, and least of all in C"

Comment: I've edited my post. I'm currently also creating an image to explain it visually.

Comment: Thank you for efforts. I'll wait :)

Comment: I've added it to my post. Just in case you have trouble understanding it: the black squares represent the checkboxes and the orange circles the radio buttons.

Comment: Oh yes, it makes sense. But how do you think, would it be more usefull if radio group will be replaced with voting and number of votes. There are 2 arrows (+1 vote, -1 vote) & total number of votes per each speciality.  + Summary area where all selected specialities are shown sorted. This summary area is also interactive (you can vote up/down and totally remove specialities from summary) ?

Comment: That's even better! You could also set a maximum number of votes globally if that's necessary.

Comment: or may be I should left checkboxes. When I select speciality - speciality selected appears in sortable summary area. And sorting is availabe in summary, no voting required?

Comment: That makes it easier yes. But one remark I'd like to make: make sure the summary area stays within the user's screen, this is applicable to scrollable areas. This way the user doesn't need to scroll up/down to check the summary area.

Comment: Finally, I implemented interface with checkboxes. When user selects checkbox,  dropdownlist with priorities appears (1..8). Default priority is the minimum that is in the gap between priorities selected earlier. For example if you select 3 specialities priorities would be 1,2,3. Then you change 3 -> 5 and select one more speciality. This speciality appears with priority 3. When speciality is deselected (user changed his mind and not interested in speciality) - dropdownlist dissapears. 

Nevertheless, thank you for conversation :).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the "List builder" design pattern.

The list builder contains two lists.  On the left side you have the source list (ie. the complete list of faculties/specialties), and on the right side you have the source list (the items chosen by the user in prioritized order).

Between the lists you have two buttons.  "Add" (arrow to the right) and "Remove" (arrow to the left), wich adds and removes items to the destination list.

In addition you put two buttons along with the destination list.  These are used for rearranging the destination list.
Eg. "Move up" and "Move down" for moving the selected item up and down.

Se examples: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511484.aspx#listBuilders

http://osdpl.fluidproject.org/designPatterns/List-Builder